# I'm trying to make a form based calculatorfor a business equation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form based calculator for a business equation which works out break-even return on ad spend.

The fucntion works, I've testred it through the console on Chrome. But this is ony when I set the variables to numbers, I'm struggling to use the data from the form to work it out.

I don't know if using a form is right for this. The part I can't figure out is linking the HTML form data to the JS variables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="main">
            <label for="rprice">Retail Price: </label>
            <input type="number" id="rprice"><br><br>
            <label for="cogoods">Cost of Goods: </label>
            <input type="number" id="cogoods"><br><br>        
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
let retailPrice = document.getElementById("rprice")
let costOfGoods = document.getElementById("cogoods")
let difference = retailPrice - costOfGoods

    function calculate () {
        return (retailPrice / difference)
     };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take in consideration:

1. to get the value of any input use attribute `.value`

```js
function calculate (){
    let difference = retailPrice.value - costOfGoods.value
    return retailPrice.value / difference 
 };
```

Add `submit` input to fire the function `calculate()`

```html
<input type="submit" value="calculate">
```

2. to get the returned value from a function you have to call it.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("main");
form.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(calculate());
});
```

Note: `event.preventDefault()` prevent the form from reloading.

```js
let retailPrice = document.getElementById("rprice");
let costOfGoods = document.getElementById("cogoods");
let form = document.getElementById("main");
form.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(calculate());
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = calculate();
});
function calculate (){
    let difference = retailPrice.value - costOfGoods.value
    return retailPrice.value / difference 
 };
```

```html
<form id="main">
    <label for="rprice">Retail Price: </label>
    <input type="number" id="rprice" ><br><br>
    <label for="cogoods">Cost of Goods: </label>
    <input type="number" id="cogoods" ><br><br>        
    <input type="submit" value="calculate">
</form>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: How do I display the answer at the bottom of the form?

Comment: It's Simply, Add a div reference it with id `display` to access it within script and change it when you click on submit by `.innerHTML`, Check out the answer I added this possibility to show the result in the html not only on the console!

Comment: Thanks for the help! One more question, I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". Is this due to the page loading with no value? –

Comment: Welcome I am glad to help, I think you should add `let form =document.getElementById("main")` and add to callback function `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the page from refreshing!

Comment: Not letting me input decimals. E.g. 23.4